# Next Js Missing origin header from a forwarded Server Actions request

Tags: reactjs, next.js

`x-forwarded-host` header with value `localhost:3000` does not match `origin` header with value `127.0.0.1:5500` from a forwarded Server Actions request. Aborting the action.
⨯ Error: Invalid Server Actions request.

my next.confg.ts for reference:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    env: {
        BASE_URL: "http://localhost:8080/eNach"
    },

    experimental: {
        serverActions: {
            allowedOrigins: [
                'http://localhost:3000',
                'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
                '*',
            ]
        }
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Next.js 14.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to not include http or https protocols, but just have the domain name.

Comment: i tried but same error